# Angular.js routes and partials for complex navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm trying to build a fairly sophisticated navigation menu with angular.js. It's going to be very similar to the main drawer navigation here: http://www.purepolaris.com/en-us/snowmobile/Pages/home.aspx

I'm pretty sure I can do this entirely with just routes and partials with maybe some controllers to further break down the content.

My question is this - I feel like this is almost too easy and I feel like I'm missing something. What else should I know before I start creating this?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

DM

Answer (score 1):

Handling nested states with Angular might be **very tricky**.
[Angular-UI's Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) allows to handle this gracefully, with the dot syntax :

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.contacts = [{ name: 'Alice' }, { name: 'Bob' }];
    }
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html'
  });
```

Comment: user1737909 thanks for the heads up. I'll let you know if this works or not. I'll be working on it more next week and let you know if I run into any issues or if I'm successful. Thanks again for the tip.